# How do I connect a ceiling fan without a light kit?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm trying to install a new ceiling fan that is controlled by one wall switch.  The fan came with a pull-chain that controls the 3 speeds;  and also comes with an optional light kit.  But I am not using the light assembly  and have removed it from the fan.  However, I noted that there is still one wiring harness that must be connected within the fan assembly...presumably  in order for the pull-chain assembly to work.

The fan comes with a black, blue, white and green wire.  The wiring at the ceiling box consists of one red, one black, one white and a green wire.  I think I know what all these wires represent in terms of the current carried in each.  My question is:  given that the light is not going to be used, do I need to connect only the black to black, white to white, and green to green wires (and cap the red wire), or do I still need to utilize the red and/or blue wires--and if so, in what way?  Thanks for any insights.

Comment: What brand ceiling fan is it? Does it have a manual?

Comment: What wires are in the switch that control the fan, and how are they connected? Green wire in the ceiling box is throwing me off a bit, I would have guessed you have a 14/3 between the switch and fan, but that should be red, black, white, and bare copper.

Comment: @gregmac Not if it's in EMT.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would follow the instructions for wiring it as if it *did* have a light kit. You, or someone else, may someday want to add one, and that's far simpler if you can just remove the cap, plug in the connector, and bolt the light fixture in place. They may still want to rewire in order to put the lights under control of a wall switch rather than or in addition to the pull chain, but if not...